# select and edit listview

Tags: c#, listview

How do I select and edit subitem in the listview in a C# program using the textbox or pop-up or new form? View my sample please and thanks, how to edit the entire row.

```
try
{
    if (listView1.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Empty items", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else
    {
        int itmCnt = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int t = 0;

        listView1.FocusedItem.Remove();
        itmCnt = listView1.Items.Count;
        t = 1;
        for (i = 1; i <= itmCnt + 1; i++)
        {
            t = t + 1;
        }
        txtTotal.Text = subtot().ToString();
        //undefined pa!!!!!!!!!!!
        int val1 = 0;
        int val2 = 0;
        int.TryParse(txtTotal.Text, out val1);
        int.TryParse(txtPayment.Text, out val2);
        int I = (val2 - val1);
        txtChange.Text = I.ToString();
    }
    btnRemove.Enabled = false;
    if (listView1.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        txtTotal.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Instead of remove, is read or edit, please help